# Heroku + Docker - cannot connect to MySQL Server on db:3306

Tags: mysql, docker, heroku, flask

Everything is working fine when I'm running locally. Now trying to deploy to Heroku. Using the following commands:

`heroku container:push web --app myApp`
`heroku container:release web --app myApp`

Below is my docker-compose file:

```
  version: '3.4'

  services:
    myApp:
      build: .
      depends_on:
        - db
      volumes:
        - .:/usr/src/app
      ports:
        - 81:3001
        - 80:3000
    db:
      image: mysql:5.7
      ports:
        - "32000:3306"
      environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somePass
      volumes:
        - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
```

Edit: one thing I notice is when I am running the app locally after running `docker-compose` the MySql server gets created on the very first run immediately after I run `docker-compose`. However this doesn't seem to happen when I release the app to Heroku (or at least it doesn't show up in the logs)... Could this be related?

Edit2:
I'm using mysql-connector in Python to connect to the DB. Below is the config file I'm using to connect:

```
    config = {
        'host': 'db',
        'port': 3306,
        'database': 'myDb',
        'user': 'root',
        'password': 'somePass',
        'charset': 'utf8',
        'use_unicode': True,
        'get_warnings': True,
    }
```

Comment: 1) firewall / ip whitelisting on Docker ? 2) MySQL user ip/host incorrect   ?????

Comment: Don't think it's 2) because the same configuration works locally.
What ip would I need to whitelist in Docker?